# Debug into the [from metadata] file in visual studio

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2019, dllimport

In my project I am using 'Execute' function of 'namespace Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient' and 'AdomdCommand' class.

[Microsoft Documentation Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdcommand.execute?view=analysisservices-dotnet#microsoft-analysisservices-adomdclient-adomdcommand-execute)

I want to debug into this Execute function implementation but when I press (Ctrl+F12) in my VS it goes to meta as shown below:

[image]

I have added the 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll' in my project assembly and also inside packages but still I am not able to go inside 'Execute' function implementation and end up at the metadeta. Please see the solution explorer:

[image]

What shall I do to import the dll so that I can debug the implementation of 'Execute' function??
Thanks!!

Comment: Might be able to find the library on GitHub somewhere? The general gyst of dll's is that you can't really debug them because they're pre-packaged.

Comment: You can try using VS2022 maybe it will solve your problem